# how to black list a command in apache2 web server

Tags: webserver, apache2, devops, matomo, system-administration

Suddenly my server start getting hang. I observed that all CPU cores are 100% in use. I used htop command to see which request/service making it overloaded. I found following request using maximum CPU in percent.

[/usr/bin/php8.1 -q /PATH_TO_MATOMO/console climulti:request -q --matomo-domain= --superuser module=API&method=CoreAdminHome.archiveReports&idSite=INTEGER_VALUE&period=year&date=2022-01-01&format=json&segment=visitorType%3D%3Dnew&trigger=archivephp&pid=A_VERY_LARGE_STRING_FOR_PID&runid=19943](https:///usr/bin/php8.1%20-q%20/PATH_TO_MATOMO/console%20climulti:request%20-q%20--matomo-domain=%3Cdomain-name%3E%20--superuser%20module=API&method=CoreAdminHome.archiveReports&idSite=INTEGER_VALUE&period=year&date=2022-01-01&format=json&segment=visitorType%3D%3Dnew&trigger=archivephp&pid=A_VERY_LARGE_STRING_FOR_PID&runid=19943)
[image]

So how I can blacklist this command in my apache2 web server?

I added following in the virtual host config file of apache2 web server but it did not work for me.

```
**RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/climulti/[^/]+/feed$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]**
```

Any help will be great favor. Thanks!

Comment: There are many threads of apache2 server running. Trying to limit them e.g., 4

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand the problem.

When I see "100% CPU" and "Matomo" together in the same sentence, I know that sometimes, upstream, is the problem where Matomo will try to run multiple archivers at once.

In Linux the solution is

1. Enabling the crontab to run the core:archive command.
2. Disabling Browser Trigger archiving in the General Settings.

In Windows, a scheduled task is the answer.

Matomo describes the solution here: https://matomo.org/faq/on-premise/how-to-set-up-auto-archiving-of-your-reports/